# Comments on code when app is published problem

Tags: programming-languages

I wanted to ask you if it is right to leave comments within the code of an app that is about to be published. Could malicious users who want to analyze the source code immediately understand how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish a software you are not (supposed) to publish your code but only file.exe that you build from it, so the source code is not there as well as your comments, if you do publish your sorce code, from your own choice, then any one can understand it even without any comments, that is a open source software.

bottom line - you can leave your comments in the code when you publish your software.